# Installer script for cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Is there any cakephp-3.0 method for SQL installer and upgrade ?. As I want to add all tables at once and also to upgrade the tables.

Comment: Read http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html